# Symfony2 fixtures

Tags: symfony, doctrine, fixtures

I have this error when trying to use d:f:l on Smyony2, i got the same error for Servicio and Usuario, so I post one example and if you help me, the other one will be fixed too.

```
  [ErrorException]
  Catchable Fatal Error: Argument 1 passed to PGE\BitacoraBundle\Entity\Tarea::setServicio() must be an instance of PGE\BitacoraBundle\Entity\Servicio, integer given, called in D:\Zend\Apache2\htdocs\PGE\src\PGE\BitacoraBu
  ndle\DataFixtures\ORM\Tareas.php on line 20 and defined in D:\Zend\Apache2\htdocs\PGE\src\PGE\BitacoraBundle\Entity\Tarea.php line 281
```

This is the code:

Tareas.php

```
<?php
namespace PGE\BitacoraBundle\DataFixtures\ORM;

use Doctrine\Common\DataFixtures\AbstractFixture;
use Doctrine\Common\DataFixtures\OrderedFixtureInterface;
use Doctrine\Common\Persistence\ObjectManager;
use PGE\BitacoraBundle\Entity\Tarea;

class Tareas extends AbstractFixture implements OrderedFixtureInterface
{
    public function getOrder()
    {
        return 3;
    }
    public function load(ObjectManager $manager)
    {
        for ($i = 1; $i < 5; $i++) {
            $entidad = new Tarea();

            $entidad->setServicio($i);

            $entidad->setFechaInicio(new \DateTime());
            $entidad->setFechaFinal(new \DateTime());
            $entidad->setDescripcion('Descripcion aqui');
            $entidad->setEstado('Pendiente');
            $entidad->setPrioridad('P1');
            $entidad->setResumen('Hola soy un resumen');
            $entidad->setSolicitante('x068753');
            $entidad->setUsuario($i);
        }
    $manager->flush();
    }
}
```

Usuario.php

```
<?php
namespace PGE\BitacoraBundle\Entity;

use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;

/**
* @ORM\Entity
* @ORM\Table(name="bitacora_usuario")
*/
class Usuario
{
    /**
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue
    */
    private $id;

    /** @ORM\Column(type="string", length=255) */
    private $nombre;

    /** @ORM\Column(type="string", length=255) */
    private $apellidos;

    /** @ORM\Column(type="string", length=255) */
    private $prbes;

    public function __toString()
    {
        return $this->getNombre().' '.$this->getApellidos();
    }

    /**
     * Get id
     *
     * @return integer 
     */
    public function getId()
    {
        return $this->id;
    }

    /**
     * Set nombre
     *
     * @param string $nombre
     * @return Usuario
     */
    public function setNombre($nombre)
    {
        $this->nombre = $nombre;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get nombre
     *
     * @return string 
     */
    public function getNombre()
    {
        return $this->nombre;
    }

    /**
     * Set apellidos
     *
     * @param string $apellidos
     * @return Usuario
     */
    public function setApellidos($apellidos)
    {
        $this->apellidos = $apellidos;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get apellidos
     *
     * @return string 
     */
    public function getApellidos()
    {
        return $this->apellidos;
    }

    /**
     * Set prbes
     *
     * @param string $prbes
     * @return Usuario
     */
    public function setPrbes($prbes)
    {
        $this->prbes = $prbes;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get prbes
     *
     * @return string 
     */
    public function getPrbes()
    {
        return $this->prbes;
    }
}
```

EDIT: I'm using Symfony 2.1.X

Comment: The message is pretty self-explanatory, you're supposed to pass a Servicio object, but you're passing an integer instead... what did you expect?

Comment: Also, you aren't telling the manager to persist anything so nothing will happen anyway. Make sure you add `$manager->persist($entidad);` for each iteration.

Comment: I forgot to write here the persist method, but I'm using it. What I want is to set an integer on setServicio, because it's linked to another table where I have the Servicio names... I was able to make this time ago, but I haven't worked with symfony last months, so I forgot a lot...

Answer (score 0):

There is no problem with the bundle, instead it says very clearly that the first argument passed to `$entidad->setServicio($i);` must be an instance of `PGE\BitacoraBundle\Entity\Servicio` and not an integer.

So you have ot get an instance of Serivcio and pass this to the setter. If you create the servicio inside another fixture, you need to look into the [sharing objects between fixtures](http://symfony.com/doc/current/bundles/DoctrineFixturesBundle/index.html#sharing-objects-between-fixtures) section of the bundle documentation.